# Why Service Discovery Like Eureka and kubernetes service doesn't preserve the whole url however IBM WSSR Does?

Tags: java, spring, microservices, websphere, service-discovery

I am Implementing a microservice application and i want to know the best practice about the service discovery.
I was using IBM WSSR and it was saving the whole endpoint as object with a key and you can fetch the endpoint using the key, but when i started to use Kubernetes service and eureka i found that it only preserve the network details like port and IP so i need to know what is the best practice in here and why uereka and kubernetess service doesn't preserve the whole URI like application context and controller path ?

I was expecting the Eureka and Kubernetess service will be the same as IBM WSSR and am wondering if there is any service discovery preserve the whole URI or not.